# page doesn't recognize small section of php

Tags: php, html, css

I have a small section of php in one of my pages that isn't running. It's the exact same code that I have running on other pages, yet on this page in particular, it won't run at all. Instead, it prints out part of the code starting immediately after "$session." I checked to make sure my include path is correct since it uses the $session variable.

It just displays the user's username if there is a user logged in. Do you see any problem with my code?

```
<div style="text-align: left; float: left; font-size: 70%; clear: both;">
            <?
                if ($session->logged_in){ 
                    echo "You are logged in as: <br>", $session->username;
                }
            ?>
        </div>
```

You can look at the whole page here (and notice how it works on other pages...well, if you take the time to log in, that is):

http://uglyfacez.com/gallery/

Comment: Have you got short_open_tags enabled? You could change it to `<?php` to see if it works

Comment: How about putting a `php` right after `<?` ?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but to no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied with my code elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe PHP [short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) are not enabled on the server?

Try this:

```
        <?php   // CHANGE HERE
            if ($session->logged_in){ 
                echo "You are logged in as: <br>", $session->username;
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

My first guess would be to try `<?php` instead of `<?`

Comment: I tried this earlier, but unfortunately it didn't change anything.